# Are there any APIs that find the shortest sea distance between two points, given the latitude and longitude?

Tags: api, geospatial, transportation

Searching online turns up websites like [this one](http://www.ports.com/sea-route/), which can return the shortest over-water distance between two *ports*, but I'm looking for something more general. Are there APIs or datasets that would allow me to calculate the shortest over-water distance between two points, given the points' latitude and longitude?

From what I've read, this is non-trivial to implement using Google Maps and the Google Maps API.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are free data sets available for distances between ports:
[www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov](http://www.nauticalcharts.noaa.gov/nsd/distances-ports/distances.pdf) or
[msi.nga.mil](http://msi.nga.mil/NGAPortal/MSI.portal?_nfpb=true&_pageLabel=msi_portal_page_62&pubCode=0005)

Also you will find some providers that give you distances between ports depending on AIS data like [marinetraffic.com](http://www.marinetraffic.com/).

If you look for an API that gives you the shortest path between two coordinates on sea, there is [Aquaplot](https://doc.aquaplot.com)

Disclaimer: I am the co-founder of Aquaplot.

Answer (score 1):

```
/*::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
/*::                                                                         :*/
/*::  This routine calculates the distance between two points (given the     :*/
/*::  latitude/longitude of those points). It is being used to calculate     :*/
/*::  the distance between two locations using GeoDataSource(TM) Products    :*/
/*::                                                                         :*/
/*::  Definitions:                                                           :*/
/*::    South latitudes are negative, east longitudes are positive           :*/
/*::                                                                         :*/
/*::  Passed to function:                                                    :*/
/*::    lat1, lon1 = Latitude and Longitude of point 1 (in decimal degrees)  :*/
/*::    lat2, lon2 = Latitude and Longitude of point 2 (in decimal degrees)  :*/
/*::    unit = the unit you desire for results                               :*/
/*::           where: 'M' is statute miles (default)                         :*/
/*::                  'K' is kilometers                                      :*/
/*::                  'N' is nautical miles                                  :*/
/*::  Worldwide cities and other features databases with latitude longitude  :*/
/*::  are available at http://www.geodatasource.com                          :*/
/*::                                                                         :*/
/*::  For enquiries, please contact sales@geodatasource.com                  :*/
/*::                                                                         :*/
/*::  Official Web site: http://www.geodatasource.com                        :*/
/*::                                                                         :*/
/*::         GeoDataSource.com (C) All Rights Reserved 2015                  :*/
/*::                                                                         :*/
/*::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::*/
function distance($lat1, $lon1, $lat2, $lon2, $unit) {

  $theta = $lon1 - $lon2;
  $dist = sin(deg2rad($lat1)) * sin(deg2rad($lat2)) +  cos(deg2rad($lat1)) * cos(deg2rad($lat2)) * cos(deg2rad($theta));
  $dist = acos($dist);
  $dist = rad2deg($dist);
  $miles = $dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  $unit = strtoupper($unit);

  if ($unit == "K") {
    return ($miles * 1.609344);
  } else if ($unit == "N") {
      return ($miles * 0.8684);
    } else {
        return $miles;
      }
}

echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "M") . " Miles";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "K") . " Kilometers";
echo distance(32.9697, -96.80322, 29.46786, -98.53506, "N") . " Nautical Miles<br>";
```

Comment: The distance between two points is different than the distance *over water* between two points.

Comment: In addition to not answering the question this is also incomplete (though one can easily find the missing deg2rad, rad2deg, and strtoupper; not all that accurate; and appears to be cut and paste from material that is copyright geodatasource.com